# Why is London City getting a virtual tower?

Tags: airport, airport-design, uk

[image]
([Source](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/video/video-1467237/UK-s-remote-digital-air-traffic-control-tower-London-City.html))

[London City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_City_Airport) is not a [remote-low-traffic airport](https://www.sesarju.eu/sesar-solutions/high-performing-airport-operations/remote-tower-two-low-density-aerodromes). Staffing a remote airport is like having lighthouse keepers. That I understand.

And yet the tower will be **closed,** and moved off-airport to [become a virtual tower](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-39960993).

All those working on the project are very happy apparently, and the press releases (and videos) don't reveal much. I don't get it. The only thing that I saw as a positive, was an augmented reality overlay on the screens that highlights nearby drones.

> (...) a critical new safety feature means the cameras will be able to pick out rogue drones near the airport, as well as light the runway at night.

Why would a major airport undergo such change? What problems are being solved?

Comment: My guess is because it only has one runway. It sounds like they’re saying the camera system is better than eyeballs anyway.

Comment: Oh heavens! Someone _please_ adjust the color settings on those monitors!!! Yes, the sun is at the left, so the right ones should be darker, but not _that_ much!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

London City is severely space-constrained, being on an island in the Thames. Moving the tower means more space for functions that cannot be moved.

> ... will also include an extended terminal building, enabling it to serve two million more passengers a year by 2025.

A high tower means substantial foundations, so you can't just stick the tower on top of another building. You have to build around it.

Comment: the higher construction in the congested airspace of London (both air traffic into LC and police and other helicopters all over the place) would also cause problems.

Comment: @jentwing -- but doesn't there have to be some sort of tower of that same height there anyway, to mount the cameras on?